# Adding an outside int into an action listener

Tags: java, int, integer

I have to do a very small project for school: making a game of tic tac toe in Java using JButtons and I have a short question.

Here's the code:

```
public void FensterAufbauen() {
    int i = 0;  
    myPanel.setLayout(null);
    myButton.setText("");
    myButton.setBounds(40,70,80,80);
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (i % 2 == 0){
            myButton.setText("X");
            }
            else {
            myButton.setText("O");
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
}
```

Now how would I add the `int i` into the action listener
(I have this for all 9 buttons so I can't just define `i` inside the listener)?
I am sorry in advance if anything here seems sloppy - I'm pretty new to Java

Comment: This does not look like Javascript

Comment: You sure you don't mean Java ;-)

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript. Apart from their name, they are very different languages.

Comment: You are correct. I made a correction to the tag. It should be java, not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

i has to be final if you want to access it from within an anonymous inline class:

```
final int i = 0;
```

That, of course, will mean you can no longer change it. Thus, instead, declare i as a non-final, private variable in the surrounding class, rather than a local variable. Or you could also declare i as a private variable inside your ActionListener, just above the actionPerformed() function.